# What does this line do, "string ret(v);"?

Tags: c++

What does this mean "string ret(v);" in the code below?

```
char t(char c)
{
    return tolower(c);
}
string toLower(const string & v)
{
    string ret(v);
    transform(ret.begin(), ret.end(), ret.begin(),  t);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Creates a new string named `ret` as a copy of `v`.

Comment: Would have been preferable to accept the string by value, though; this can avoid unnecessary copies in some cases.

Comment: Check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Read [copy-constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) or [basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean `string ret(v);` [...]?

This creates a copy of the function argument `v` with the name `ret`. This copy is then altered by the call to `std::transform` and returned by value.

Note that `v` is passed as a `const`-qualified reference. It can't be changed within the function. That's why a copy is made to create a string object that can be modified an returned to the caller as a result.